# Meta+Shift-Return in iTerm2 on Mac not working

Tags: org-mode, osx, terminal-emacs, modifier-key

Have you met the case that Emacs in iterm2 on Mac does not recognize  `M-S-RET` (Meta(Option)+Shift+ Return key)?  I guess it's related to the modifier key conversions in terminals.

`M-S-RET` is used in org-mode

I tried `describe-key` in Emacs and got `M-[1 3; 4`
I think `M` stands for meta, 13 is the ASCII code of `return`, 4 is the CSI u code for `Shift+Alt`  see http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/

Comment: You might want to clarify what what `describe-key` says, because the spacing in your `M-[1 3; 4` looks wrong.  Also to see the full sequence of chars received by Emacs when you press `M-S-RET` `view-lossage` (aka `C-h l`) is a better choice (`describe-key` will try to guess when the sequence ends and that guess is not always the one you need).

Comment: When testing in iTerm2, I've set up the left option key (Mac) to be Esc+, and report modifier CSI u key.  In Option set sa Normal, M-S-RET is always equal to M-RET in terminal.
I've tried to Use `C-h l`, it says `;`

Comment: I've tried to Use `C-h l`, it says `ESC [ 1 3 ; 4 [nil]`

Comment: What happens if you put `(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "ESC [ 1 3 ; 4") (kbd "S-RET"))`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.

Comment: ```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "ESC [ 1 3 ; 4 u") (kbd "M-S-RET"))
```
When the key-sequence is not set, "ESC [ 1 3 ; 4 u" are splited into an unknow "ESC [ 1 3 ; 4" and an extra "u" command.